# How to select data from differents servers with a single query?

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a challenge! I need select from 4 different tables from 4 different servers.

Example:

```
Select * from server1.tableS1.sys.view
Select * from server2.tableS2.sys.view
Select * from server3.tableS3.sys.view
Select * from server4.tableS4.sys.view
```

How I can make the select in the same query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`UNION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) is what you're looking for.

```
Select * from server1.tableS1.sys.view
union all
Select * from server2.tableS2.sys.view
union all
Select * from server3.tableS3.sys.view
union all
Select * from server4.tableS4.sys.view
```

You might want to do:

```
Select 'server1',* from server1.tableS1.sys.view
union all
Select 'server2',* from server2.tableS2.sys.view
union all
Select 'server3',* from server3.tableS3.sys.view
union all
Select 'server4',* from server4.tableS4.sys.view
```

... if you need to identify which rows came from which.

Comment: Don't need open a connection with the others servers?

Comment: @EmanuelF You need to add them as a linked server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ff772782.aspx